# using PHP in a sign up form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on creating a sign up form and I've looked at some tutorials and this is what I have so far in my PHP file.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NAMEHERE", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        header("location: http://mycoinrewards.com");
    die('Failed to connect to database');
}

function NewUser()
{
        global $dbh;
        $username = trim($_POST['username']); //at a minimus clear whitespace.
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $password =  trim($_POST['password']);
        $options = [
            'cost' => 12, //higher = more lower= less. you want it to take around 0.4 seconds for security reasons!
        ];
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options); // hashed password for storage!
        $stmt = $dbh->perpare("INSERT INTO login (username, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bindValue(2,$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(3,$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(4,$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
        echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
        }
}

function SignUp()
{
global $dbh;
if(!empty($_POST['username']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-Up.html, is it empty or have some text
{
        $user = trim($_POST['username']);
        $pass = trim($_POST['password']);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ?") ;
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!password_verify($password, $selected_row['password'])) // check password agaisnt stored hash
        {
                newuser();
        }
        else
        {
                echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";
        }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        SignUp();
}
?>
```

I get an error on line 43 when I use a form to submit it that says this Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() in /home/swarm/public_html/logininfo.php on line 43

I was wodnering if anyone can help me fix my code! Thanks!

Comment: what is your PHPs version? password_verify is available from `5.5.0` and newer

Comment: Are you using PHP 5 >= 5.5.0? The docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php say you need that.

Comment: `password_verify ()` is only available from PHP 5.5. There's a shim on Github that does the same thing for lower versions. I'll try to find the link.

Comment: I actually am a total noob at this, but how can I see what version of PHP I'm running via FTP or cpanel?

Comment: User land shim: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat